# my flutter app won't open image path file

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to save an image added by the user in the database as a string, my application will take the path of the inserted image, but the problem is when another device open the application this error appears

```
Cannot open file, path =
'/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.sad
(OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 13)
```

but in the same device, the image will appear

any idea how to solve this?

Comment: But this is logic, right? you are trying to open an image witch exists in another device! you need to save an image in the cloud, not in the device, then save the image path in a cloud database like that all devices will have access to the image!

Comment: the image path is actually saved in the database, var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera );
    ImageNearby = image.path; >> rhis path is saved in the database